The reset() problem of RecurDyn simulation model with Gym for reinforcement learning training
I'm trying to integrate a RecurDyn simulation model with Gym for reinforcement learning training. The simulation model communicates with RecurDyn through an FMU file(FMI2.0) in Python. However, when I'm wrapping the model as a Gym environment, I'm having trouble with the reset() method. If I call fmu.reset() directly, I find that in the next iteration, the model is not restored to its initial state, regardless of how I call fmu.instantiate(), fmu.setupExperiment(startTime=start_time), fmu.enterInitializationMode(), and fmu.exitInitializationMode(). Additionally, if I don't use fmu.reset() and instead use the API to execute modelDocument.ModelSetting.ResetAllSettings(), the model returns to its initial position, but the forces and joints are not reset. As a result, the model jumps back to its previous position in the next iteration. Does anyone have a solution to this problem? Can you help me, please?
